# Fortify sourceanalyzer error

Tags: ant, task, fortify

When I am running sourceanalyzer ant task for my java and jsp code analysis, I am getting error like:

> Unable to create directory /export/home/olbbbld/.fortify/sca5.10/build

What causes this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is a directory for SCA build cache. It seems to be that you do not have the required permission to create this directory.